# Setting a css background image to an inline SVG symbol?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

I know external svg files can be linked to background images:

```
background-image: url(Icon.svg);
```

and symbols id's can be targeted from an external svg file:

```
background-image: url(Icons.svg#Icon-Menu);
```

but how can I set a background image to an **inline** svg symbol? *(As below)*

*My svg is at the top of my web page body and not in an external file.*

**I want `.test` background image to be the `#Icon-Menu` symbol.**

```css
.test{
  background:#ddd url('../#Icon-Menu');
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="Icon-Menu" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <title>Menu</title>
      <path d="M93.417,5.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V8.333 C96.417,6.679,95.071,5.333,93.417,5.333z" />
      <path d="M93.417,40.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V43.333 C96.417,41.679,95.071,40.333,93.417,40.333z" />
      <path d="M93.417,75.333H6.583c-1.654,0-3,1.346-3,3v13.334c0,1.654,1.346,3,3,3h86.833c1.654,0,3-1.346,3-3V78.333 C96.417,76.679,95.071,75.333,93.417,75.333z" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this (at least in the way you are attempting) and I'm not sure **why** you would want to.

Comment: @Paulie_D I wasn't sure if it was or not. I know svg can be used as background. I was just curious as it would save a lot of htl markup if i could do it all in css

Comment: An image has to be a complete file.

Comment: Forget the spec, this makes perfect sense right? 

"Gosh!" —Napolean Dynamite

Comment: @Paulie_D I have this requirement too - my use case is that I have no control over markup (I can't include an SVG tag within the element in question) so need to use :before / :after but I need the flexibility of styling various parts of the image using classes / ids within the SVG (which you don't get with an external file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An image must be a complete file.

From the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement)...

> The ‘image’ element indicates that the contents of a complete file are to be rendered...

The same is true for background-image etc.

Comment: Not sure why this was chosen (and upvoted). It doesn't provide a complete answer. The link provided by @A__ is far more helpful

Comment: @Majo0od in what way is "you can't do this" an incomplete answer when it references the specification to say why. There are some ways you might be able to achieve something that looks similar if you change the markup but you can't display a symbol which is what the OP has requested.

Answer (score 4):

@Robert Longson

thats right. But you can do it this way.
But symbol is not the way it will work. Unfortunatly you have to use "g" or something like that to reference.

```
body {
  background: url(http://www.broken-links.com/tests/images/faces.svg#devil-view);
}
```

http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/ByvKJq

It will not work if the svg is in the Markup.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment. Well, it's sort of an answer, but it is phrased as a comment, which makes it hard to read in this format which is meant for complete answers, not comments

Comment: Codepen link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

(1) one possible way with **inline SVG** would be to use symbols and DIV absolute layering:

```
<a class="preview-modal__device-icon-link" ng-click="setPreviewWidth('phone')">
   <svg class="preview-modal__device-icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-phone">
   </use></svg>
</a>
```

(2) Second solution would be to use a Data URI:
there is a good info here: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
using this tool: [Mobilefish.com online conversion tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php)

CSS:

```
.logo {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]");
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]">
```

Comment: a css background with a base64 of an inline svg with a href to a local symbol doesn't seem to work

Comment: where do i need to add the url at "data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]" ?

Comment: @AlexNikonov, you don't use an url with data-uris. With a data-uri, you base64-encode the whole contents of the file (for example with the mobilefish link in the post), and paste that code in place of the [data]. The file itself is not accessed by the data-uri.